# Swift structure not updated after modifying in a block

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift and having some problems about structures and blocks. When user edits his education information and clicks save button, I send a request to the server and update local data in the success handler. Here I wrote an `editItem()` function in the class `EditController` and an `editEducation()` in the class `UserModel` structure:

```
class EditController: UITableViewController {

    //...

    func editItem<T>(item: T, completion: () -> Void) {
        switch selectedType {
            case .Education:
                let educationItem = item as! EducationModel
                // self.user is a object of type "UserModel"
                user!.editEducation(index: selectedRow, educationItem: educationItem) {
                    // breakpoint 2 here
                    completion()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    //...

}

struct UserModel {

    //...

    var education = [EducationModel]()
    //EducationModel is also a structure

    //...

    mutating func editEducation(#index: Int, educationItem: EducationModel, completion: () -> Void) {
       let manager = HTTPClient.sharedManager
       manager.POST("/user/education/update",
           parameters: [
               // params
           ],
           success: { (task, responseObject) in
               if responseObject["status"] as! Int == 0 {
                   self.education[index] = educationItem
                   // breakpoint 1 here
                   completion()
               } else {
                   println(responseObject)
               }
           },
           failure: { (task, error) in
               println(error)
           }
       )
    }

    //...

}
```

The problem is, despite that `self.education` is successfully updated when the program reaches breakpoint 1 (as commented above), `self.user.education` still contains the old data at breakpoint 2. If I move

```
self.education[index] = educationItem
```

outside the POST request, the data updates as expected at breakpoint 2. I tried delaying by adding dispatch at breakpoint 2, but it still won't update. I also printed the memory address of related variables, but it provides no useful information. I now handle this by adding a `controller` parameter to `editEducation`, pass `self` in `EditController` and force update the `user` property of the controller. I think it's not a proper solution. So is there a better way to do this?

**Update 1**

I tried turing UserModel into a class and it solves the problem, but I don't want to do that because: first some behavior of other parts of the app may go strange if I make that a class and second I have to turn other tens of models into class to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing here is the difference between value types (struct) and reference types (class). You should read the blog post on Apple's website about the differences: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Basically, once you pass a struct into a block it gets copied instead of referenced so you're working on a brand new copy. With class, you get a reference to your original copy.

Comment: I tried printing the memory of self in editEducation() outside and inside the success block, turns out they are the same. Does that mean the value is not copied when entering the block?

Comment: They're copied *on write*. All reference types will be the same instance even if copied until they're modified. I'm guessing you examined the address *before* you modified it?